# Change text style midway through a string

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out how to change the font style mid way through a string. So far the best way I've come up with is to mess with the `horizontalalignment` parameter:

```
self.ax.text(0.7, 0.1, 'BOLD', style='italic', weight='bold', 
             horizontalalignment='right', 
             transform=self.ax.transAxes, size=24)
self.ax.text(0.7, 0.1, ' ITALIC', style='italic', 
             horizontalalignment='left', 
             transform=self.ax.transAxes, size=24)
```

but this seems ugly, and more importantly it's not very robust: suppose I want three styles, then what? Isn't there some way to change the style mid way?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use LaTeX for this:

```
fig, ax = subplots()
x = linspace(0, 2 * pi, 1000)
y = sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y)
rc('text', usetex=True)
ax.annotate(r'$\sin$ wavez is \textbf{N}\textit{e}ato', (3, 0.1), size=15)
```

[image]